# What is the highest level instantaneous spell requiring an attack roll?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

At low levels attack rolls are very common, but this far every spell I found over level 2 needs a save. What is the highest level **instantaneous, damaging** spell requiring an attack roll?

Anything above Scorching Ray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Mordekainen's Sword, at 7th level

PHB 262:

> You create a sword-shaped plane of force that hovers within range. It lasts for the duration.
>   When the sword appears, you make a melee spell attack against a target of your choice within 5 feet of the sword. On a hit. the target takes 3d10 force damage.

Comment: Your answer made me realize I did not phrase the question correctly. I would ask another question, but it is too similar to this one, so the engine does not let me. I have to modify this.

Answer (score 3):

### Wish at 9th level

PHB 288:

> The basic use of this spell is to duplicate any other spell of 8th level or lower.

So you can use it to duplicate any "instantaneous, damaging spell requiring an attack roll".

Honestly, you can probably find better uses for wish, but if you really wanted to, nothing prevents you from using it to blast something.

Comment: "I wish to cast Eldritch Blast at that guy!"